# Access array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I cannot seem to understand why I cannot access an array I get send back by PHP.

I send this back when AJAX makes a call: `$response['success'] = true;`

I do this by `echo json_encode($response);` in my PHP file.

Now I want to access it in Javascript, but response.success doesnt work, it logs 'undefined' in the console. Now I check the response, and that is this: `{"success":false}`

But if I check for `if(response.success)` it always sends back false, because `response.success is undefined`. Does anyone know what I mean and what is causing this issue?

This is my AJAX call:

```
$$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url + "applogin.php",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {
        username: e,
        password: p
    },
    //dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);

        if (response["success"]) {

            window.localStorage["username"] = e;
            window.localStorage["password"] = md5(p);

            mainView.router.loadPage('beurslist.html');
        } else {

            console.log("Your login failed");
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error- Status: " + textStatus + " jqXHR Status: " + jqXHR.status + " jqXHR Response Text:" + jqXHR.responseText)
    },

});
```

Comment: Show the full code of AJAX request processing

Comment: see above! i edited the question with the ajax call

Comment: `response.success` should be the way. Are your sure you are returning the correct JSON? What does `console.log(response)` output?

Comment: You have to set `dataType` option to `json`. Otherwise the response will be treated as `html` (by default)

Comment: @hindmost - From the docs: *`dataType` (default: **Intelligent Guess** (xml, json, script, or html))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax-call will return a string, you need to decode it with `JSON.parse`. You'd get something like this then.

```
$$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url + "applogin.php",
  crossDomain: true,
  data: {
    username: e,
    password: p
  },
  //dataType: 'json', 
  success: function(r) {
    var response=JSON.parse(r)
    console.log(response);
    if (response["success"]) {
      window.localStorage["username"] = e;
      window.localStorage["password"] = md5(p);
      mainView.router.loadPage('beurslist.html');
    } else {
      console.log("Your login failed");
    }
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("Error- Status: " + textStatus + " jqXHR Status: " + jqXHR.status + " jqXHR Response Text:" + jqXHR.responseText)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed the way, i feel stupid for overseeing such a simple mistake.

Comment: @HuubS, it happens to the best of us

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @SZenC is fine, there's a point though about best practices:

The reason jQuery didn't recognize the response as JSON is because the server probably didn't send a Content-type header, so just add to your server-side code a call to -

```
header('Content-type: text/json');
```

You won't need the explicit call to `JSON.parse` in each API call, you'll get better integration with test tools, and your app will be better self-documented for other folks who use/will-use this code (including yourself should your code need some future maintenance).

In any case it is advised also to document the expected input on the client side by either explicitly specifying `dataType` as `json` or by making the API call using a shortcut method such as `$.getJSON()`.